# Telerik control visibility

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, telerik, silverlight-5.0

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">


    <telerik:RadTabControl Foreground="Black" TabOrientation="Horizontal" TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab Item A" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab Item D" Visibility="Collapsed" />

    </telerik:RadTabControl>


</Grid>
```

The above code throws error in my application. Problem is

```
  <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab Item A" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab Item D" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

If i have at least one visible tab control, my apps loads fine else it throws exception and crashed my apps.

Exceptions:

"An unhandled exception - System.InvalidOperationExdeption: UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect"

Trace:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.InvalidOperationException: UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be     called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect. 
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TabStripPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single     inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

Any idea? I can't reproduce this outside of my application.

Comment: `throws exception and crashed` if you mention exception so please add message and/or stack trace.

Comment: I edited the question with the exceptions. I cannot get it to break visual studio eventhough i turned on all the exceptions. Internet explorer crashed and came up with the above error.

Comment: Updated with more stacktrace.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception indicates the layout system cannot compute the size of an UIElement.
As you've seen, this occurs in your XAML if no tab item is visible.

So if you can, specify a fixed size for the tab control (Width=XXX).

Else, try to collapse the whole tab control instead of all of the individual tabs.

Comment: i tried specifying width/height on individual tabitem, on grid. Does not work.

Comment: Then you'll have to file a bug with Telerik.